# Twist-onacci Sequence

Tags: number-sequence, word-sequence

I started with a well known sequence that follows a simple rule:

> `1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34...`

Then I decided to twist it up a bit, and got this sequence:

> `1, 1, 4, 5, 8, 10, 15, 17, 23...`

I thought that was interesting, so I changed the rules a different way and got this:

> `1, 1, 4, 7, 11, 16, 22, 28, 34...`

Hoping that combining both changes would make something even more interesting, I was disappointed that it generated this:

> `1, 1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6...`

First, can you tell me **how I generated each sequence.** Once you've figured that out, see if you can **change the starting values of the last sequence so it doesn't end in a loop.**

Good luck!

---

<sub>Edit: Upon closer examination, the second task may not be possible. So instead, I would like a proof (formal or informal) that all possible inputs will eventually end in a loop.</sub>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

<sup>(Now with correct handling of numbers above 9, plus the longest loop.)</sup>

**Explanations for the sequences**

These were clued in by familiarity with sequence A
and by the [word-sequence](/questions/tagged/word-sequence) tag.

```
      Sequence A
      1,    1,    2,    3,    5,    8,    13,   21,   34, . . .
```

> ```
>     |     |     |     |     |     |      |     |     |
>     1  +  1  =  2     |     |     |      |     |     |
>           1  +  2  =  3     |     |      |     |     |
>                 2  +  3  =  5     |      |     |     |
>                       3  +  5  =  8      |     |     |
>                             5  +  8  =  13     |     |
>                                          .     .     |
> ```

```
      Sequence B
      1,     1,      4,      5,       8,        10,   15, 17, 23, . . .
```

> ```
>     |      |       |       |        |          |     |   |   |
>     1 + "one"  =   4       |        |          |     |   |   |      "one" = 3 (letters)
>            1 + "four"  =   5        |          |     |   |   |     "four" = 4
>                    4 + "five"  =    8          |     |   |   |     "five" = 4
>                            5 + "eight"  =     10     |   |   |    "eight" = 5
>                                     8 + "onezero" = 15   |   |  "onezero" = 7
>                                                .     .   .   |
> ```

```
      Sequence C
      1,    1,     4,      7,      11,      16,   22,  28,  34, . . .
```

> ```
>     |     |      |       |        |        |     |    |    |
>  "one" +  1  =   4       |        |        |     |    |    |
>        "one" +   4  =    7        |        |     |    |    |     "one" = 3 (letters)
>              "four" +    7  =    11        |     |    |    |    "four" = 4
>                     "seven" +    11  =    16     |    |    |   "seven" = 5
>                             "oneone" +    16  = 22    |    |  "oneone" = 6
>                                      "onesix" + 22 = 28    |  "onesix" = 6
>                                                  .    .    .
> ```

```
      Sequence D
      1,      1,      6,      6,      6,   6,   6,   6,   6, . . .
```

> ```
>     |       |       |       |       |    |    |    |    |
>  "one" + "one" =    6       |       |    |    |    |    |  "one" = 3 (letters)
>          "one" + "six" =    6       |    |    |    |    |  "six" = 3
>                  "six" + "six" =    6    |    |    |    |
>                          "six" + "six" = 6    |    |    |
>                                     .    .    .    |    |
>                                          .    .    .    |
> ```

**Informal proof that a sequence like D is destined to loop**

> All numbers above 14 (“onefour”)
>  are more than twice the letter counts of their spellings.
>
> ```
>    1  <  2 x  3 "one"         8  <  2 x  5 "eight"         15  >  2 x  7 "onefive"
>    2  <  2 x  3 "two"         9   > 2 x  4 "nine"          16  >  2 x  6 "onesix"
>    3  <  2 x  5 "three"      10  <  2 x  7 "onezero"       17  >  2 x  8 "oneseven"
>    4  <  2 x  4 "four"       11  <  2 x  6 "oneone"        18  >  2 x  8 "oneeight"
>    5  <  2 x  4 "five"       12  =  2 x  6 "onetwo"        19  >  2 x  7 "onenine"
>    6  =  2 x  3 "six"        13  <  2 x  8 "onethree"      20  >  2 x  7 "twozero"
>    7  <  2 x  5 "seven"      14  =  2 x  7 "onefour"       21  >  2 x  6 "twoone"
> ```
>
> ⇒
>  The sum of letter counts in the spellings of any two numbers above 14
>  will be less than the larger of those two numbers.
>  
>  ⇒
>  The sequence cannot increase indefinitely.
>  
>  ⇒
>  The sequence will have a limited set of possibilities
>  for consecutive-term pairs.
>  
>  ⇒
>  At least one consecutive-term pair will be repeated.
>  
>  ⇒
>  A repeated consecutive-term pair will be followed by a loop
>  because each successive term is determined
>  solely by its preceding consecutive-term pair.

**Longest loop for a sequence like D**

> ```
>      Sequence E
>      9,       9,        8,       9,       9,        8,   9,   9,   8,   9, . . .
>
>  "nine" + "nine" =      8        |        |         |    |    |    |    |   "nine" = 4
>           "nine" + "eight" =     9        |         |    |    |    |    |  "eight" = 5
>                    "eight" + "nine" =     9         |    |    |    |    |
>                              "nine" + "nine" =      8    |    |    |    |
>                                       "nine" + "eight" = 9    |    |    |
>                                                     .    .    .    |    |
>                                                          .    .    .    |
> ```

Sequence E, with a repeating cycle of 3 terms,
seems to be the only loop that resembles sequence D
that also repeats more than one term.
Three loops repeat single terms:
**6** (sequence D itself), **12** or **14**.

Sequence E was found by looking at sequence D’s addition table,
but only the portion with numbers that can be sums as well as summands.

> ```
>                                      oneone    onezero
>                            seven     onetwo    onefour
>          six      nine     eight     onesix    onefive   onethree
>   +       3        4         5         6          7         8
>       ____________________________________________________________
>      | .-----.                                                    .-------------------.
>   3  | | six |   seven     eight      nine     onezero    oneone  | Loops may be      |
>      | |  3  |     5         5         4          7         6     | found by starting |
>      | '-----'            .------.                                | from cells within |
>   4  |  seven    eight    | nine |  onezero     oneone    onetwo  | the outlined      |
>      |    5        5      |  4   |     7          6         6     | regions, which    |
>      |          .------.  '------'                                | contain every sum |
>   5  |  eight   | nine |  onezero    oneone     onetwo   onethree | that is no larger |
>      |    5     |  4   |     7         6          6         8     | than either of    |
>      |          '------'           .--------.                     | its summands.     |
>   6  |  nine    onezero    oneone  | onetwo |  onethree  onefour  |                   |
>      |    4        7         6     |   6    |     8         7     | Any loop includes |
>      |                             '--------'.--------------------' at least one such |
>   7  | onezero   oneone    onetwo   onethree | onefour   onefive    sum.  (Though not |
>      |    7        6         6         8     |    7         7       all such sums are |
>      |                                       |                      parts of loops.)  |
>   8  |  oneone   onetwo   onethree  onefour  | onefive    onesix  .-------------------'
>      |    6        6         8         7     |    7         6     |
>      |                                       '--------------------'
> ```

Comment: That's it! I debated putting the "word-sequence" tag in, because I thought it might make it too easy, but decided to keep it anyways.

Comment: [Relevant(ish) video about these sequences](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LYKn0yUTIU4)

Comment: Quite a relevant video, @Holloway, motivating the addition of what seems to be the longest cycle possible for the last sequence here

Comment: Thanks for your awesome ASCII art. If you used Imgur, I would be in trouble (see my profile).